# Prey Throbber using CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I'm migrating to web development and wanted to learn CSS animations better. I was playing [Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2017_video_game)) last night and realized the "throbber" on the elevator screen would be interesting to reimplement. For anyone not familar with the game, it can be seen briefly [here](https://youtu.be/NA9IRxAextQ?t=51) (although that's not required for the review).

Here's the end result as a snippet:

```css
.throbber-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  background-color: #2eb9e8;

  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

.throbber-wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;

  background-color: #93e2ff;

  // For the sake of the animation so it starts without full boxes waiting to be animated.
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;

  animation: cellShrink 1000ms infinite;
}

@keyframes cellShrink {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    opacity: 10%;
  }
}

.throbber-wrapper .b2 {
     animation-delay: 62.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b3 {
     animation-delay: 125ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b4 {
     animation-delay: 187.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b8 {
     animation-delay: 250ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b7 {
     animation-delay: 312.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b6 {
     animation-delay: 375ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b5 {
     animation-delay: 437.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b9 {
     animation-delay: 500ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b10 {
     animation-delay: 562.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b11 {
     animation-delay: 625ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b12 {
     animation-delay: 687.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b16 {
     animation-delay: 750ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b15 {
     animation-delay: 812.5ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b14 {
     animation-delay: 875ms;
}
 .throbber-wrapper .b13 {
     animation-delay: 937.5ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="throbber-wrapper">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b4"></div>
  <div class="b5"></div>
  <div class="b6"></div>
  <div class="b7"></div>
  <div class="b8"></div>
  <div class="b9"></div>
  <div class="b10"></div>
  <div class="b11"></div>
  <div class="b12"></div>
  <div class="b13"></div>
  <div class="b14"></div>
  <div class="b15"></div>
  <div class="b16"></div>
</div>
```

The color isn't perfect, but that's not my main concern. The main challenge when writing this was getting the timing of the squares right and written in a sane way (I think I only achieved the first goal there). A full cycle is one second, divided by 16 cells gives 62.5ms, so I decided to delay the animation of each cell by 62.5ms longer than the previous cell. That unfortunately meant *manually IDing each cell, and manually writing delays for each cell*. I was able to reduce the duplication a bit using SCSS nesting, but it's still atrocious.

## What I'd like help with:

- This code has a disgusting amount of duplication. I would like to know about any tricks that can neaten it up.
- Any other CSS, SCSS, or even HTML tricks that can help make this code cleaner.

HTML (this is a component, not a full page):

```
<div class="throbber-wrapper">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b4"></div>
  <div class="b5"></div>
  <div class="b6"></div>
  <div class="b7"></div>
  <div class="b8"></div>
  <div class="b9"></div>
  <div class="b10"></div>
  <div class="b11"></div>
  <div class="b12"></div>
  <div class="b13"></div>
  <div class="b14"></div>
  <div class="b15"></div>
  <div class="b16"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.throbber-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  background-color: #2eb9e8;

  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

.throbber-wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;

  background-color: #93e2ff;

  // For the sake of the animation so it starts without full boxes waiting to be animated.
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;

  animation: cellShrink 1000ms infinite;
}

@keyframes cellShrink {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    opacity: 10%;
  }
}

.throbber-wrapper {
  & .b2 {
    animation-delay: 62.5ms;
  }

  & .b3 {
  animation-delay: 125ms;
  }

  & .b4 {
    animation-delay: 187.5ms;
  }

  & .b8 {
    animation-delay: 250ms;
  }

  & .b7 {
  animation-delay: 312.5ms;
  }

  & .b6 {
    animation-delay: 375ms;
  }

  & .b5 {
    animation-delay: 437.5ms;
  }

  & .b9 {
    animation-delay: 500ms;
  }

  & .b10 {
  animation-delay: 562.5ms;
  }

  & .b11 {
    animation-delay: 625ms;
  }

  & .b12 {
    animation-delay: 687.5ms;
  }

  & .b16 {
    animation-delay: 750ms;
  }

  & .b15 {
  animation-delay: 812.5ms;
  }

  & .b14 {
    animation-delay: 875ms;
  }

  & .b13 {
    animation-delay: 937.5ms;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using SCSS, why not use a [SCSS `@each` loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) with `:nth-child()` for setting the animation delay? It would also remove the need for classes on your child elements.

Store the animation order of elements in a [list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists) and loop over it. Use the index of your position in the loop for an `:nth-child()` selector, and the current value as the animation delay multiplier.

**SCSS:**

```css
@keyframes cellShrink {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    opacity: 10%;
  }
}
.throbber-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #2eb9e8;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
.throbber-wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #93e2ff;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: cellShrink 1000ms infinite;
}
$order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13;
@each $block in $order {
  $n: index($order, $block);
  .throbber-wrapper div:nth-child(#{$n}) {
    animation-delay: #{($block - 1) * 62.5}ms;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="throbber-wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh cool, I haven't gotten to loops yet (I ended up getting side tracked). Does this work though? I haven't run it, but it looks like the order would be off on every second row.

Comment: Ah, I forgot you had it going boustrophedon. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: Lmao. TIL there's a word for this pattern. That's good to know. I've never seen that word before. And I'm assuming you could fix that with a conditional in the loop, or something like nested loops where the inner alternates direction? I haven't fully explored what SCSS is capable of.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've updated my answer. Instead of conditionals or nested loops, just storing the animation order in a list is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: I didn't know SCSS had lists either. Apparently, I got side-tracked far too early. Thank you! This is a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

## Thank to @RemasteredArch on Reddit for the hint.

They suggested using variables and `calc` to calculate the delays. After learning how to do that, I got it working, and it got rid of ~60 lines of manually written and calculated delays. It also lets me easily change the animation speed now (I might even be able to make it an input to the component).

### The highlights:

1. I made some variables. Unfortunately for now, the `--n-cells` variables isn't useful when creating the grid, and is only used for calculating delays:

   ```
   .throbber-wrapper {
       --full-animation-cycle-time: 1000ms;
       --n-cells: 16;
       . . .
   ```
2. The entire massive nested `.throbber-wrapper {` block at the bottom was replaced by:

   ```
   .throbber-wrapper > div {
       animation-delay: calc(var(--order) * var(--full-animation-cycle-time) / var(--n-cells));
   }
   ```

Now the speed of the animation can be changed by changing `--full-animation_cycle-time`, and all the delays don't need to be recalculated for the animation to run properly.

Unfortunately, snippets don't appear to support variables (?), so I can't show it here but it runs identically.

HTML:

```
<div class="throbber-wrapper">
  <div style="--order: 1"></div>
  <div style="--order: 2"></div>
  <div style="--order: 3"></div>
  <div style="--order: 4"></div>
  <div style="--order: 8"></div>
  <div style="--order: 7"></div>
  <div style="--order: 6"></div>
  <div style="--order: 5"></div>
  <div style="--order: 9"></div>
  <div style="--order: 10"></div>
  <div style="--order: 11"></div>
  <div style="--order: 12"></div>
  <div style="--order: 16"></div>
  <div style="--order: 15"></div>
  <div style="--order: 14"></div>
  <div style="--order: 13"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.throbber-wrapper {
  --full-animation-cycle-time: 1000ms;
  --n-cells: 16;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.throbber-wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;

  background-color: #0d6efc;

  // For the sake of the animation so it starts without full boxes waiting to be animated.
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;

  animation: cellShrink var(--full-animation-cycle-time) infinite;
}

@keyframes cellShrink {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    opacity: 10%;
  }
}

.throbber-wrapper > div {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--order) * var(--full-animation-cycle-time) / var(--n-cells));
}
```